# Adding CSS or JS to Woodstock JSF page

Tags: jsf, netbeans, woodstock

I tried to make it work for over 2 hours before I gave up.

Using JSF (the Woodstock Library) **is required** (even though I hate it now!).

How can I add CSS or JavaScript to a JSF page and have it work?

Comment: Which libraries are you using? Facelets? Richfaces? Tomahawk? Icefaces?... Please be a little more precise.

Comment: i am using the woodstock thing

Comment: Keep in mind the Woodstock library isn't being supported anymore.

Comment: "I have to use JSF . I hate it!" - Do you hate it just because you don't know how to do things with it (like embedding CSS)? Do you hate programming also? ;)

Comment: JSF is brilliant. Woodstock is a shame. Fortunately it's dead as of now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the usual suspects: `<script>` and `<style>`. Depending on your JSF version, you may need to wrap them in a `<f:verbatim>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Heres how I do it:

```
<f:view>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h:outputText value="Test style" style="background-color: red;" />
        <h:outputText value="Test style class" styleClass="testClass" />
    </body>
</html>
</f:view>
```

Answer (score -1):

simply use :

```
   <h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="css/style.css"  />
   </h:head>
```

for JS uses this tag :

```
 <h:outputScript>
```

Comment: Sorry, this won't work. OP clearly said he's using Woodstock. Your syntax works only from JSF 2.0 on.