# how to implement CSS and JavaScript in JSf File?

Tags: javascript, css, jsf

Am working on a time tracker application using jsf. i have done with the validation part .
Now can any one help me out how to implement CSS and JS in the jsf.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special. You can do it in the same way it's done without jsf. Here is some examples: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-jsfcss1/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The point of using JSF is to avoid writing JavaScript unless it is absolutely necessary. JSF allows you to [specify the .css file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073663/adding-css-or-js-to-a-jsf-page) or to skin the complete application using an already available skin which would vary depending on your choice of JSF implementation. You just need to add one tag to your [faces-config.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213177/how-do-you-create-your-own-adf-faces-skin).

```
<skin-family>myskin</skin-family>
```

If you can be more specific regarding what you are trying to accomplish through JS, I am sure that BalusC and others here will suggest you an easier way to do it through JSF itself..

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions to your question, depending on what you want to do.

1. You can use

   ```
   <h:outputScript ... />
   <h:outputStylesheet ... />
   ```

   to include certain scripts or stylesheets in a page.
2. You could use a template to include standard-stylesheets and scripts
   that should be available on every page.
3. You could use the "styleClass" and "style" attributes of JSF
   components for CSS-Styling and the JS event handler like onclick,
   onblur, etc. to invoke any javascript you like.

HTH